# Need help connecting Microsoft SQL Server to Microsoft Power BI

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, odbc

I have recently joined a new company and I have a project where I am trying to connect a Microsoft SQL Server to Power BI to automate a report and I am running into some issues. I have successfully connected the server to a SQL environment in DBeaver so I know that the host name and port number are correct.

I have not successfully created an ODBC connection for though I have tried. Using the System DSN, I have tried both the SQL Server and the ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server and both failed connecting. With the SQL Server option, I made up a name and user the following format for the server host:port and then used my windows NT credentials on the next page and left everything else as default all the way through testing the connection. I got the below error for this one:

```
Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver Version 10.00.19041
Running connectivity tests...
Attempting connection
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]Invalid connection.
TESTS FAILED!
```

For the ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server option, I did the same settings with defaults and I got the below error:

```
Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server Version 17.04.0000
Running connectivity tests...
Attempting connection
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]. 
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
TESTS FAILED!
```

When I try and import the data into Power BI using the SQL Server option, and I put the host:port into the server slot and the SQL in its place, it then ask for me to sign in. I am using my windows credentials which is accurate and so I press connect and I get the below error:

```
"The server name provided doesn't match the server name on the sql server ssl certificate 
Please contact your administrator or see the link below for more information. Alternatively,
you could change your Connection encryption settings. Would you like to continue using an 
unencrypted connection?"
```

I am not sure how to fix this so I can run my SQL Server script in Power BI. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Since dblib and ODBC can have different connection string keywords you probably need to address this issue first, `SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87].`

Comment: This suggests that you have `Encrypt=YES` or similar in your connection string: `The server name provided doesn't match the server name on the sql server ssl certificate`. Since SQL Server uses a self-signed X.509 certificate by default you either need to install its Public Key in your trusted certificate store or you need to include `TrustServerCertificate=YES` in your connection string.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning where would I put in the TrustServerCertificate=YES? I am not familiar and don't have access to the admin settings of the server itself. I do have computer admin access though.